# Problema con foreach con JSON

Tags: php

Estoy recorriendo un .json con el ciclo foreach, pero pasa un problema que solo cuando hay solo 1 elemento en el ciclo, me da error pero cuando hay 2 elementos o mas si funciona. 
Este es mi código

```
    $url = 'data.json';    
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
    foreach($data['data']['games']['game'] as $i) {
       echo $i['league'];
    }
```

Error que me arroja:

> Notice : Undefined index: league in
>
> Warning : Illegal string offset 'league'

De esa forma funciona cuando hay mas de 1 elemento en el json, pero da error si es solo 1 elemento.
Pero para que funcione cuando solo hay 1 elemento fue hacer lo siguiente:

```
    foreach(array($data['data']['games']['game']) as $i) {
       echo $i['league'];
    }
```

Pero no funciona cuando hay mas de 1 elemento.
Hay forma de que funcione cuando hay 1 o mas elementos en el array?.

El error que me arroja es el siguiente:

> ```
> Notice: Undefined index: league in
> ```

Comment: Es el siguiente: http://gd.mlb.com/components/game/aaa/year_2019/month_09/day_21/master_scoreboard.json  Si quieres que salgan mas elementos solo cambia /aaa/ por /mlb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realmente estás trabajando con dos JSON estructurados de forma diferente, y no puedes hacer otra cosa que leer cada uno de acuerdo a su estructura.

### Primer JSON

En él no hay un array en la clave `game`, su estructura es así:

```
   "data":{  
      "games":{  
         "game":{  
            "links":{  
               "away_team":"/clubs/index.jsp?cid=t560",
               "box_link":"/milb/stats/stats.jsp?gid=2019_09_21_mvaaaa_tijaaa_1&t=g_box&did=milb",
               "home_team":"/clubs/index.jsp?cid=t5010"
            },
            .... ... etc
```

La clave para entender lo que es un array en JSON es este símbolo: `[` todo lo que empieza por él en un JSON representa un array. Si observas, después de `game` lo que hay es esto: `{`, lo cual indica que ahí `game`es un objeto simple, no un array.

Eso implica que no puedes leerlo como array. Puedes acceder al valor de forma directa.

---

#### Segundo JSON

En él si hay un array dentro de `game`, porque vemos que esa clave empieza por `[`

```
   "data":{  
      "games":{  
         "game":[  
            {  
               "links":{  
                  "away_audio":"bam.media.launchPlayer({calendar_event_id:'14-567535-2019-09-21',media_type:'audio'})",

                ... ... etc
```

Aquí si puedes usar el `foreach`, porque en `game` hay un array y puedes leer cada uno de sus miembros o parte de ellos en un bucle.

---

#### Solución para ambos casos

Si quieres un código que maneje ambas posibilidades, puedes hacer esto:

```
 $url = 'data.json';    
 $mJson = json_decode(file_get_contents($url)); #Atención aquí, no uso true
 if (is_array($mJson->data->games->game)){
     foreach ($mJson->data->games->game as $game) {
         echo $game->league.PHP_EOL;
     }
 }else{
     echo $mJson->data->games->game->league;
 }
```

Simplemente pregunta si en `game` hay un array, si lo hay, procede a leer dentro de un bucle, si no, busca el dato directamente.

**Salida caso 1:**

```
MEX
```

Eso es todo lo que hay en `league` en ese primer JSON.

**Salida caso 2:**

```
AA
NN
NN
NN
AA
AA
AA
NN
AA
AA
NA
NN
NN
AA
NN
```

Todos los valores que tiene la clave `league` en el array de objetos.

**NÓTESE** que he evitado el `true` al usar `json_decode`, dado que no me interesa convertir mi JSON a array, prefiero trabajarlo tal cual es, un JSON, pudiendo usar la notación `$objeto->clave` en la lectura, la cual es más elegante que si lo convirtiera a array: `$clave["valor]`.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Eres mi dios, tenia días rompiéndome la cabeza, no me había fijado que su estructura era diferente. Mil Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Está bien lo que estás haciendo. Lamentablemente el array viene formateado distinto según el caso.

Lo que podes hacer es antes de correr el foreach chequear que tipo de información obtuviste. Si existe la clave `0` del array `game` entonces recorremos directamente eso. Sino, creamos un array como bien estás haciendo.

```php
$url = 'data.json';    
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
$games = isset($data['data']['games']['game'][0]) ? $data['data']['games']['game'] : [$data['data']['games']['game']];

foreach($games as $i) {
    echo $i['league'];
}
```